# 組込みで 4word 以上をバースト転送させる時の記述方法は？

Tags: linux, c

組込みに関しての質問です。
マイコンと外部メモリ(実際はFPGA)が16bitデータバスで接続されており、バースト転送でデータを送りたいと考えています。

C言語上、以下のように記述すると、2word までであればバースト転送されることは確認できたのですが、4word, 8word のバースト転送の場合、どのように記述すればよいのでしょうか？

- 1word(16bit)の場合: `*((unsigned short *) addr) = data;`
- 2word(32bit)の場合: `*((unsigned long *) addr) = data;`

追記：
情報不足で申し訳ありません。環境を追記いたします。

- マイコン：TI製AM3358
- 開発環境：ti-psdkを使用し、linuxを起動
- 概要：
  　linux上のアプリを作成。
  　マイコンのGPMCバスとFPGAが接続。
  　GPMCバスでデータ転送する際に、Burst書き込み/読み込みを行う

Comment: マイコンと回路次第なのでこれだけでは何とも言えないです

Comment: たぶん DMAのことでは？ … (仮に) DMAを指しているのなら, (バースト転送をサポートしてるはずの) DMAコントローラーがどのように(バスなどに)繋がっているかが分からないと分かりません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。環境に関して追記いたしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

バースト転送させる、という命令はCには規定されてませんので無理ですね。
CPUやコンパイラ環境によってはそのようなオプションもあるものもあるかもしれないので、そこらへんはお使いのコンパイラのマニュアルを読めばいいかと思います

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。そうですよね。一応CPUのマニュアルを再度確認してみます。

Comment: まあ、ルネサスのコンパイラなんかだと、その特殊命令用のインライン関数が用意してある、とかやってますねー